# npm does not recognize updates in package from repository

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a node.js package installed from a private repository (Bitbucket). Each time I make changes, I use `npm version` to bump the version in `package.json`.

I would expect that when running `npm update` on the project that uses that module, that npm would recognize the changes and update the new version. Instead, I have to delete my package and install again.

Is this the expected behavior for installations from private repositories, or am I missing something? If it is the expected behavior, how can I "detect" changes in my module that comes from a private repository ?

**EDIT**

Running `npm update --verbose package-name` produces the following output:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/home/manu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/home/manu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.6.0/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'update',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   package-name]
npm info using npm@3.10.3
npm info using node@v6.6.0
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

**EDIT2**

Here's how the dependency is declared in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "package-name": "git+https://user:password@bitbucket.org/myrepo.git"
}
```

Comment: How do you have the version specified in the client code's package.json? Also, are you running npm clean cache prior to updating?

Comment: @LarryTurtis I wasn't running `npm cache clean`, but I tried and the result was the same. The version is specified as described in npm documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies.

Comment: Is this a private npm repository or a private repository hosted by another host?

Comment: @zero298 Private repository hosted by bitbucket

Comment: I tried it locally against a github repo and I could not reproduce what you saw. The closest I have seen so far are packages heavily cached on heroku  and cloudfoundry but this is obviously not the case here.
Have you tried to run `npm update --verbose <packagename>`.

Comment: @DanielKhan Please check output in edit of question

Comment: Can you include in your question a snippet from the `package.json` that consumes the package that's in the private repository? So that it's clear how you are defining the dependency.

Comment: @cartant I've updated the question per your request

Comment: Which version of Node / npm is that?

Comment: @DanielKhan npm@3.10.3, node@v6.6.0

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see the behaviour you have described with dependencies declared like this: `"mdl-stepper": "ahlechandre/mdl-stepper.git"`. For me, it always updates the dependency, even if nothing has changed. There is an old, possibly related issue (that seems to have been closed unresolved) with a long conversation [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727).

Comment: It's just a blindshot, but could you please try `npm install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{user}/{repository}.git`.

Providing the username:password in the URI seems odd to me. I'd rather go for using deployment keys.

Comment: @DanielKhan We chose not to use ssh keys because we were having problems configuring our platform service with them, perhaps it's something I will need to revisit in order to solve the problem

Comment: @cartant That's exactly the workaround we've been using, leading to lengthier deploys. Nice find, I'm guessing that I have to continue to use the `rm -rf node_modules` workaround...

Comment: @ManuelReis, the way I usually work around this issue, is by using a commit hash in the git url, like so: `<user>/<repo.git>#4ef38fb2adc73304ae1ea87b0d607ad7fadc4d01` (works for GitHub). This way you know which commit `npm i` will install. You still have to update it every time you want a fresh version - but at least it's better than `rm -rf node_modules`.

Comment: @ManuelReis this comment might not be very helpful, but FYI: I realized long time ago that `npm update`  is not very reliable (and not easy to understand what it does, and what it doesn't do) and I don't use it at all; the most reliable and easy to understand way is sadly `rimraf $depname` and then `npm install`.